# Boto3 - Get the % of free volume space

Tags: amazon-web-services, boto3

I am writing the python script, that should increase the size of volume, if the free disk space is smaller than 20%.

Here is what I have already written:
import boto3

```
ec2 = boto3.resource('ec2', region_name='eu-central-1')
client = boto3.client('ec2', region_name='eu-central-1')
instance = ec2.Instance('xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx')
volumes = instance.volumes.all()
for v in volumes:
    print(v.id, v.size)
    volume = ec2.Volume('v.id')
    response = client.modify_volume(VolumeId=v.id, Size=8, DryRun=False)
```

As you can see, I've found a way to display disk space and change it's size. How can I get the % of free disk space?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

`Boto3` works at the hypervisor layer and can start/stop instances, get disk size etc., which are possible without getting OS access. But the information you are asking - available disk space (like available memory, open FDs etc.,) can be reported by OS only.  So there is no way to get the information you are asking for using `Boto3`.